# Some texts automatically underlined in iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1, My problem is text automatically underlined on some buttons in the application

[image: sample Image]

Is there any settings available to remove the underline?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a change to show which button labels are pressable.

You should go to `Settings > General > Accessibility` and turn on/off **Button Shapes** and then revisit the app in question. You should only see underlines and shapes when this control is on, and this is to indicate what buttons that look like text are actually tappable for those with accessibility needs.